# Downvotes on my valid answers

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

Recently I am getting downvotes on my valid answers without any comment. I am not new to Stack Overflow, and I know that sometimes we get downvotes for no reason, but the past few days it is happening continuously at least once in a day. It is a bit annoying.

I already flagged my last downvoted answer to a moderator. What else can I do? Can moderators do something about it? What will they do if it is done by a single person?

Sample answers:

- *[SQL query - return one result per ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41382170/sql-query-return-one-result-per-id/41382195#comment69966834_41382195)*
- *[Is there a way to set the comparative in a WHERE clause to IS NULL or IS NOT NULL based on a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510626/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-comparative-in-a-where-clause-to-is-null-or-is-not-nul/41510716#41510716)*
- *[What is the difference between NOT condition and NOT() in Oracle and MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504329/what-is-the-difference-between-not-condition-and-not-in-oracle-and-ms-sql-serv/41504527#41504527)*

Adding to the above answers just now got a downvote on a question which has been asked 11 months ago:

*[SQL Server Rounding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869952/sql-server-rounding-issue)*

The whole point of the question here is: I am not taking downvotes seriously or feeling bad about it. But this could make a new user stop answering or contributing to Stack Overflow.

Comment: And you expect the moderator to do what exactly?

Comment: @Patrice - May be some sort of action against voting irregularity

Comment: and it's voting irregularity why? You got a downvote. If it's enough to trigger a reversal from the serial voting script.... It will. If it is not enough, flagging for mod attention will not change that

Comment: @Patrice - Cool :D

Comment: @Patrice - will the  serial voting script considers both question and answer ? because just now got a downvote on a question which has been asked 11 months ago :D

Comment: and why is the fact it'e 11 months old mean anything here? We build answers for future visitors. An answer you posted 11 months ago was seen today and it didn't help. The details of the script are kept private ao people don't game it

Comment: @Patrice - That is one theory and another theory could be someone did it on purpose ;)

Comment: which,AGAIN, is caught by the serial downvoting script.

Comment: Why are you wasting the time of moderators with flags for downvotes? I could understand your doing so if you had 537 rep, but at almost 54**K** rep, you should understand how this site works and how to appropriately use flags. If you don't, then spend some time in the help center. If there's an issue with serial voting, the automated script will catch it. If it doesn't, there's nothing a moderator can do to help you. You got downvotes. Someone thought your answer was not helpful, or you ticked someone off enough that they thought it was worth a couple of rep points. No mod help for that.

Comment: @KenWhite - I already said, I dont care much about am getting downvotes. All am saying is this could make some new talented user stop contributing to SO. Already I got 3 downvotes on the posts I mentioned after asking this question :D

Comment: If you don't care, why are you flagging and wasting a moderator's time for such nonsense? If two points rep is so important to you that you're actually suffering over losing it, you're here for the wrong reason. I get random downvotes frequently, usually after I've downvoted a question or answer and left a comment explaining why. I don't run and tattle to a moderator, even though I'm pretty sure who D/V'd. You probably got the D/Vs because people read your answers by linking to them here (which is clearly what you wanted - you just didn't get the results you planned).

Comment: @KenWhite - Last three lines utter nonsense bro. I just added that last question only after getting down vote not when I asked this question. I didn't plan anything. Thanks for your concern :)

Comment: Again, a moderator can't do anything about voting. If there's serial voting, the automated script will detect it. If it doesn't, you can contact SO **employees** via email and ask them to look into it. A moderator has no control over how people vote, and wasting their time looking at your useless flags just to decline them is a waste of resources. Your concern over new users is ridiculous; if they post poor quality questions or answers and get downvoted, they'll learn to do better in the future. You're simply wasting moderator time because you got a downvote. Learn that rep only counts here.

Answer (score 20):

> I already flagged my last downvoted answer to a moderator. What else can I do? Can moderators do something about it? What will they do if it is done by a single person?

I'm actually surprised that, given your reputation, you weren't aware of the automated voting fraud detection script which runs every day to roll back anomalies in voting.  The moderators themselves can't do anything about this; they'd rely on the script *first*.

Besides, there are only a handful of downvotes on your content as it stands.  It's really nothing to get up in arms about, which is why I also doubt that the automated script is going to kick in and reverse any of this.

To put this another way, how can you truly disambiguate this - which looks like users simply disagreeing with your answers or not thinking your question was well-researched - to actual voting abuse?

To your point about the answers being correct - simply put, someone else thought otherwise, or felt that your angle of approaching it wasn't correct, or [keys were lost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/175248).  The only thing you can do is to correct what you believe is wrong, and if you feel nothing is left to correct, then accept it for what it is and don't get too worked up about others not agreeing.

Comment: I am already aware of that script to reverse serial upvoting or downvoting but I just want to know whether moderators can do anything about it. If no also why cant they make it visible to moderators

Comment: If you knew about the script, why are you looking to moderators to take any kind of action *before* the script had a chance to run...?

Comment: script is not going to capture my scenario for sure. In that case moderators should be able to do something about it..

Comment: I pose the question again:  how are **any** of your downvotes indicative of voting fraud?  I see nothing in your reputation history to suggest that you're being targeted, so the moderators wouldn't be capable of doing anything at all.

Comment: Because all three are valid legitimate answers.. There is no reason to downvote

Comment: That's your opinion (and it's a strong one at that).  I'll revise my answer to incorporate that view.

Comment: Again, all am saying is this could make some new talented user stop contributing to SO

Comment: @prdp quick question for you: considering people can downvote for any reason they want..... A) how can a moderator determine what is invalid? B) even if it is invalid for the mod.... Voting is personal, so we can't know the reasons. No mod will invalidate three downvotes.....

Comment: @Patrice - A) Op clearly said it helped him and he marked it as answer B) I agree on voting is personal but it not just three votes I asked a question because of 3 votes but the same things is happening to N number of users and they are asking here that is the difference

Comment: @prdp consider stack's goal to help FUTURE visitors. You helped OP. Non-OP visited your post. Didn't help him. Downvoted. Simple, no? Or,there is someone downvoting and targetting you and skirting at the edge of the script. With only 3 (4 with the question now) downvotes, hard to tell. My main point is that... While you possibly are right (I mean at a glance your answers look good so it might be someone targetting you and not your content, who knows).... There is truly nothing to be done but suck it up :/

Comment: @Prdp You have a whole bunch of posts (2,644). It's entirely possible one person downvoted two of them and a second person downvoted one, all on the same say *by coincidence*. Improbably things happen too. Also posting this on meta may explain the downvote on your question since it draws attention to yourself and the meta people tend to be a hard crowd.

Comment: Man, I hate how you can't fix stupid typos/spelling errors in comments you wrote at 4:30am :-(